# WinForms Draw, Then Move Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, rectangles

I have a rectangle I am trying to draw in a WinForms project using C#. I am drawing the rectangle on the form's Paint event:

```
private void onPaintHandler(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1)) {
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, this.Height - 100, this.Width, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, -1, this.Height - 100, this.Width, 100);

        brush.Dispose();
        pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am interested in being able to move the rectangle. If I change the location values at runtime in the code above, I see the same rectangle drawn in multiple places, but not actually "moved".

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to persist the coordinates and call invalidate() whenever you change them.

Comment: You don't need to call `pen.Dispose()`...that's what the `using` is for.  And put one on the `Brush` for the same reason.

Comment: @Taw I called `Invalidate()` on the form and it works as expected. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **persist** the coordinates in a class variable
and call `Invalidate()` whenever you change them.

This will cause the initial `Paint` event to fire, in addition to the times when Windows notices, that the control's or the form's surface is no longer valid.